# getting data out of YML

Tags: yaml, jekyll

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am trying to include a html icon on hover.
This is my code:

```
<div class="country">{% include icons/home/icon-america.html %}</div>
```

this works fine, but the icon has to be different on each hover, so i tried this:

```
<div class="country">{% include icons/home/icon-{{project.country}}.html %}</div>
```

And this is my YML:

```
home:
- {folder: 'thumb_1', name: 'Chaffee', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de chaffee en nog meer', link: 'chaffee.html', country: 'america'}
```

this is not working, is there a way to get this work?
Thanks in advance.

This is my HTML

```
  <div class="thumb-container">

        {% for project in site.data.settings.home %}

        <a href="{{project.link}}" class="thumb-unit">

            <div class="backPic" style="background-image:  url(assets/img/home/{{ project.folder}}/thumb.jpg)"></div>
            <h3>{{ project.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{ project.text}}</p>
            <div class="thumb-overlay"></div>
            <div class="country">{% include icons/home/icon-america.html %}</div>

        </a>

        {% endfor %}

    </div>
```

Wim

Comment: Not very clear what you want to do. Where `{{project.country}}` come from ? Is it a `for` loop in your `site.home` variable ? Can you show your `icons/home/icon-???` template ?

Comment: {{project.country}} comes from my YAML "icon-america.html" is just a html (with an SVG in it)document i have been trying to link, but i have also "icon-museum.html", "icon-russia.html" and so on. I have multiple divs that all have to show a certain icon.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Your links are pointing to site page or to external pages (eg: github, ...) ?

Comment: the above HTML is working like i want it to, but it only shows "icon-america.html" on each div. I have one div that has to show "icon-ussr.html" another "icon-museum.html" and so on. I dont know if i explain it right, but i am Dutch, and this is the best i can do in english.

Comment: Can you put your code on a github repository ?

Comment: this is the repository https://github.com/wimhuiskes/militair-mobiel-depot

Comment: I solved this one by putting the svg's in a seperate folder, and linking to them like this: {folder: 'thumb_1', country: 'america', name: 'M24 Chaffee', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de chaffee en nog meer', link: 'chaffee.html'} and the html like this: <img src="assets/img/home_icons/{{ project.country}}/icon.svg" alt="" />

Answer (score 0):

I solved this one by putting the svg's in a seperate folder, and linking to them like this:

```
{folder: 'thumb_1', country: 'america', name: 'M24 Chaffee', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de chaffee en nog meer', link: 'chaffee.html'}
```

and the html like this:

```
<img src="assets/img/home_icons/{{ project.country}}/icon.svg" alt="" />
```